how to force a register in the DUT from e?
I have a DUT, which I need to force some of its registers. How to do it ? I used a plain force with the full path of RTL DUT but it didn't work as expected.
attached is the DUT hierarchy which I want to force . Do I have to use "system_command" ?

use simulator_command("force : = {"1"}")

use:  simulator_command("force :signal_path = {\\"1\\"}");
